# Is it good idea to use Dispatcher.Main with delay( )?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

`fetchData()` is `suspendCoroutine` function, so it is implemented on other thread.

`viewModelScope` is bound to `Dispatchers.Main`: this should be used only for interacting with the UI and performing quick work.

So should I have `delay()` in `Dispatcher.Main` or should I move out it?

```
fun loadData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      delay(START_DELAY)
      when (val result = fetchData()) {
        is Response.Success<IData> -> {}
        is Response.Failure -> {}
      }
    }
  }


fun fetchData(){
    return suspendCoroutine { cont ->}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer is it can stay, `delay` will not hurt Main thread, it will not block it. This coroutine inside Main Dispatcher will be suspended, while other coroutines inside Main will continue to run.